# are sharply and steadily opposite?

Tags: word-meaning, adverbs

Is this natural to say that something is changing sharply and steadily?

> Prices have been climbing sharply and steadily.

In this sentence I want to say that prices increase sharply, not gradually. At the same time, prices increase without any  interruptions, so I decided to add steadily. But I guess these to adverbs may conflict because steadily also means gradually according to [dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/steadily?q=steadily).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Sharply" implies a change in the rate of increase:

> prices rose sharply on Tuesday

Implies that the rate of increase on Tuesday suddenly changed.

Whereas "steadily" means the opposite: with no changes in the rate of increase. Thus the two are opposites.

Instead of "sharply and steadily" I propose "rapidly":

> Prices have been climbing rapidly.